# Compare two bigrams lists and return the matching bigram

Tags: python, list, nlp, nltk, list-comprehension

Please suggest how to compare 2 bigrams lists and return the matching bigram only. 
From the below example lists, how to return the matching bigrams **['two', 'three']**.

```
bglist1 = 
[['one', 'two'],
 ['two', 'three'],
 ['three', 'four']]

bglist2 = 
[['one', 'six'],
 ['two', 'four'],
 ['two', 'three']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just test for if the bigram is in the other list of bigrams.

```
out = list()

for x in bglist1:
    if x in bglist2:
        out.append(x)
```

This would give you a list of lists that are in both bglists.